# new line problems when parsing xml

Tags: php, xml, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I use an xml upload option in my website, but the problem is that when I import I have all new lines are skiped and words are just sticking together, I use php,
here is how I do xml to array:

```
$listings = Parser::xml($xml)['Listing'];
```

here is how I save the text:

```
foreach ($listings as $item) {
    $listing->description = e(strip_tags ($item ['Web_Remarks']));
    $listing->save();
}
```

`e()` is laravel function to escape before saving to DB, `strip_tags()` - this function strips a string from HTML, XML, and PHP tags

here is the input xml sample: http://xml.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1107&pid=8245&acc=8807

here is the end result and as you can see the text is sicked together : http://www.propertygiant.ae/listing/view/9908

so I need a way to have new lines in my text, pls help

Comment: pls give an example of the input

Comment: http://xml.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1107&pid=8245&acc=8807

Comment: pls post how the result should look

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving with following:

```
$listing->description = e(strip_tags ($item ['Web_Remarks']));
```

Use `nl2br()` for new line.

```
$listing->description = e(nl2br(strip_tags ($item ['Web_Remarks'])));
```

Comment: thanks but it won't work coz it is just adding new line at the end of the text

Comment: Using `nl2br` gave me new line.